# Counting tab views in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-insights

How do I go about counting basic tab views, like Wall, Videos, Photos, etc.? I see this information in the new Insights/Reach, but can't find it in the Graph API at all.

I can see all my tabs in the {page id}/tabs graph, but there are no view counts (and what a great place to put them... Facebook, are you listening? ;)

I did try a Page Insights on the tab page ID that I got from the /tabs graph, e.g.:

{tab page id}/insights

... but the user doesn't seem to be an admin for those pages (they're run by an agency user). I'll look to gain Admin access to those tab pages, then post back here when I find out. Any insight until then would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Any insight until then would be greatly appreciated.*"

You will want to use the FQL insight table to get at specific insight values. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

Comment: As I mentioned in my other post 1) there are no totals in the insights, and 2) FQL is deprecated, which is why I made a point of mentioning the Graph API.

Comment: No, FQL is NOT dead.  Nor is it being deprecated.

Comment: As far as totalling items, why is that an issue?  Computers are really good at summing a list of items.

Comment: ... except there's only the past 3 days of data... no where near what we need to compile a total.

Comment: well, blessed be you sirs, I'm a SQL nut, so hearing that FQL is alive and well is a joyful thing indeed. A couple of you brought this distinction to me attention, thanks to you both.

Comment: absolutely... just got here, so I'm looking backwards to see what I have access to at the outset.

Comment: So, there's no way to access that data in either the Graph API *or* the FQL?

Comment: It doesn't appear that Facebook is saving the older data, per your findings, so I'd say you should save the data points you retrieve in your own datastore.

Comment: I'll have to grab the UI data and store it as a legacy value, then accumulate going forward. Thanks for the heads up, I'd still be chasing this one otherwise.